# regular expression is_fraction : Python : regex

Tags: python, regex

please help me with this:

Is Fraction

Create a function is_fraction that accepts a string and returns True
if the string represents a fraction.

By our definition a fraction consists of:

An optional - character
Followed by 1 or more digits
Followed by a /
Followed by 1 or more digits, at least one of which is non-zero (the
denominator cannot be the number 0).

Tip

Modify the is_fraction function in the validation module.

Your function should work like this:

```
>>> is_fraction("")
False
>>> is_fraction("5000")
False
>>> is_fraction("-999/1")
True
>>> is_fraction("+999/1")
False
>>> is_fraction("00/1")
True
>>> is_fraction("/5")
False
>>> is_fraction("5/0")
False
>>> is_fraction("5/010")
True
>>> is_fraction("5/105")
True
>>> is_fraction("5 / 1")
False
```

This is what I've got so far:

```
def is_fraction(string):
    """Return True iff the string represents a valid fraction."""
    return bool(re.search(r'^-?[0-9]+\/[0-9]+$', string))
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've written so far?

Comment: yes so far i have come up with: 
def is_fraction(string):
    """Return True iff the string represents a valid fraction."""
    return bool(re.search(r'^-?[0-9]+\/[0-9]+$', string))
this is not True for; divide by '0'... :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, you need your denominator to be a sequence of digits, at least one of which is not `0`. This can be modeled using the regex `0*[1-9][0-9]*`

So your validation method now becomes:

```
def is_fraction(string):
    """Return True iff the string represents a valid fraction."""
    return bool(re.search(r'^-?[0-9]+/0*[1-9][0-9]*$', string))
```

Comment: I think a better regex will be `r'^-?[0-9]+/0*[1-9][0-9]*$'` - it involves less backtracking and note that `/` does not have to be escaped in Python regex patterns.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you're right. I've updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did this as follows:

```
def is_fraction(frac):
  reg_frac = (
    r'^[\d-]{1,}'
    r'/'
    r'0*[1-9]\d*'
    r'$'
  )
  return bool(re.search(reg_frac, frac))
```