# Creating a generalize rule for replace()

Tags: python

I am trying to replace a bunch of different values in a file that I am working with. The full file that I am working with is very large so I am editing each line of the file and writing a new file. I am not worried about having two large files, I just don't want to edit the original. So I am using `replace()` to replace values. The problem is that there are quite a few values that need to be replaced. However, there are some general rules that are followed.

1. `0/0` will always be replaced by 0
2. `./.` will always be replaced by -
3. Any fraction outside `0/0` and `./.` will be replaced with 1

The problem that I am running into is with part 3, where any fraction other than 0/0 and ./. will be replaced with 1. My initial thoughts were to create some kind of function that replaced any value > 0, however, some of the fractions in this file have a zero in the fraction, for example, `0/1` or `0/2`, which in normal mathematics equal to 0. What I am trying to avoid here is typing out every combination of fractions in the file and adding them into their own `replace()`. What I am wondering is if there is a way to create a generalized rule for `replace()` where anything outside of `0/0` and `./.` is converted to 1's?

Here is the code that I am working with

```
with open("output.txt","w") as out:
    for line in open(input, "r+"):
        li=line.strip()
        tabs = li.split("\t")
        geno = tabs[9:]
        geno = [i.split(':')[0] for i in geno]
        geno = [q.replace("0/0", "0") for q in geno]
        geno = [q.replace("./.", "-") for q in geno]
        geno = [q.replace("0/1", "1") for q in geno]
        geno = [q.replace("0/2", "1") for q in geno]
        geno = [q.replace("1/1", "1") for q in geno]
        geno = [q.replace("1/2", "1") for q in geno]
        #there are hundreds of combinations of crations to add here
        # ... 
        # ...
        geno = [q.replace("1/95", "1") for q in geno]
        # ...
        geno = [q.replace("95/95", "1") for q in geno]
        geno = '\t'.join(geno)
        extract = (f"{tabs[0]}\t{tabs[1]}\t{geno}\n")
        #print(extract)       
        out.write(extract)
```

Here is an example of a list that `replace()` is being used on

```
['0/0', './.', '0/2', '0/0', './.', '0/0', './.', './.', '0/2', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/2', './.', './.', '0/0', './.', '4/4', '0/0', '0/4', '0/0', './.', './.', '0/7', '6/9', './.', '4/4', './.', './.', '0/1', '0/4', '0/4', '0/9', './.', './.', '0/0', '0/0', './.', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/0', '0/4', '0/4', '5/5', './.', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '11/11', '5/5', '0/0', '0/0', './.', './.', './.', '0/0', '4/4', '0/0', '1/3', './.', '4/4', '0/0', '0/0', './.', './.', './.', '0/8', '0/0', './.', '0/4', '0/3', '0/9', '0/12', '0/4', '0/4', './.', '0/8', '0/0', '0/0', '0/4', '0/0', '0/0', '0/4', '0/0', './.', '0/1', './.', './.', './.', '0/0', '0/8', '0/7', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/3', './.', '0/0', '0/2', '0/7', './.', './.', './.', '0/2', './.', '3/3', '0/0', './.', '0/2', '0/0', '0/0', '0/9', '5/5', '0/1', '0/0', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/0', '0/4', '0/0', './.', '0/0', '0/0', './.', './.', '10/10', './.', './.', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', './.', './.', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/0', './.', './.', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/3', '0/0', '0/0', './.', './.', '0/4', './.', '0/0', '0/4', '0/4', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '9/10', '0/1', '0/4', '0/0', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', './.', './.', '0/5', '8/8', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/4', './.', './.', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/3', './.', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '0/1', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '0/4', './.', '5/8', './.', '4/4', '0/0', '0/1', '0/2', './.', './.', './.', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '0/4', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '0/10', '0/0', './.', './.', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/8', '0/8', '0/0', '0/0', '0/11', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '1/1', '0/0', '0/10', './.', './.', '9/9', '0/0', '0/10', '0/0', '0/0', '0/8', '1/1', '5/5', '0/0', './.', '0/0', '8/10', './.', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/0', '0/9', '0/9', './.', './.', '0/0', '8/8', '0/7', '0/0', '0/8', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '0/6', '0/0', '0/0', '4/4', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '10/10', '0/11', '3/3', '9/9', '0/10', '0/1', '4/4', './.', './.', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/1', '0/0', '0/4', './.', '0/2', '0/0', '0/0', '0/7', '0/0', '0/0', './.', './.', './.', '0/4', '0/0', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '4/4', '0/3', './.', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/5', '0/0', './.', './.', '0/4', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '0/3', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/4', './.', './.', '0/0', '8/8', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/10', '0/0', './.', './.', './.', './.', '0/11', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/1', './.', '0/0', '0/9', './.', '1/1', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/0', '0/4', './.', '0/5', '0/0', '0/5', '0/0', '0/0', './.', './.', '0/4', './.', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/4', './.', '0/0', '4/4', './.', './.', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '0/0', '0/3', '0/0', './.', './.', '0/8', '0/0', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/3', '0/4', './.', '0/0', '0/4', './.', '0/0', '0/2', '0/0', '0/4', './.', '0/0', '4/4', '0/0', '0/10', './.', '10/10', '0/0', '0/0', '0/12', '0/0', '0/0', './.', './.', '1/4', './.', '0/0', '0/4', './.', '0/5', '9/9', './.', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '2/2', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/4', '0/0', '0/0', './.', './.', '0/4', '3/3', '3/3', '0/0', '0/5', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/4', '0/0', './.', '0/0', '0/5', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', './.', './.', '0/0', '0/4', './.', '5/5', '0/0', './.', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '0/0', '0/4', '0/0', '0/3', './.', '11/11', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/0', '4/10', '0/0', '0/0', '10/10', '0/0', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/0', '8/8', '5/5', '10/10', '4/4', './.', '1/4', '0/0', '0/10', '0/2', '0/0', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/9', './.', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/1', '0/0', '5/5', '0/3', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '1/8', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/2', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/5', './.', './.', '0/0', './.', './.', './.', '0/9', './.', '0/9', '0/0', '0/0', '2/2', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '0/0', '0/9', '0/0', './.', '0/0', './.', './.', './.', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '9/9', './.', '0/0', '0/4', '4/4', '3/3', './.', '0/0', './.', '9/9', '4/4', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/1', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '5/5', '0/0', '0/0', '0/7', '0/5', '0/0', '0/10', './.', '0/9', '0/0', '0/0', '0/2', '0/0', '4/4', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/4', '0/0', '4/4', './.', './.', '0/0', '10/10', './.', '0/4', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/9', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', './.', './.', './.', './.', '0/0', '0/1', '0/5', '0/0', './.', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '0/0', '0/4', './.', './.', '0/5', '4/4', '0/0', '0/9', './.', '7/8', '0/1', './.', '0/5', '0/0', '0/12', '0/0', '7/7', '0/0', '0/0', '3/3', '0/4', '3/5', './.', '0/1', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', './.', './.', './.', '0/2', '0/0', '0/10', './.', '0/3', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/0', './.', '3/3', '0/2', '0/1', '0/4', './.', '0/0', './.', './.', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/9', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/1', '0/0', '0/4', '0/0', './.', '9/9', '4/9', '0/0', './.', '4/4', '4/4', './.', './.', './.', './.', '0/4', './.', '0/0', './.', './.', '0/9', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/7', '0/0', '0/0', '9/9', '0/4', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/11', '0/0', './.', './.', '0/2', './.', '0/0', './.', '2/8', '0/0', '0/4', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '0/9', '0/0', '0/0', '0/2', './.', '0/0', '0/4', '0/1', './.', '4/4', '0/11', '0/0', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/3', './.', './.', '0/0', './.', '10/10', '0/0', './.', '0/9', '0/1', './.', '0/0', '5/5', '0/0', './.', './.', '0/7', './.', '0/4', '0/0', '4/4', '0/1', './.', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '0/0', './.', '4/9', '0/8', '0/0', './.', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/8', '0/0', '0/2', '0/0', '0/5', '0/0', '0/0', '5/5', '0/0', '0/0', './.', './.', '0/8', '0/4', './.', '0/2', '0/0', '0/0', './.', './.', '0/4', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', './.', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/0', './.', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '4/4', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0', '7/7', '0/3', '0/0', './.', '9/9', './.', '0/0', '0/0', '0/0']
```

Here is an example of the text file. NOTE that this is a must smaller file with less complex fractions.

```
chr1    10397   .   CCCCTAA C   943.64  VQSRTrancheINDEL99.00to100.00   AC=1;AF=0.5;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=1.07;ClippingRankSum=-0.322;DP=11;ExcessHet=0.2139;FS=1.056;InbreedingCoeff=0.1828;MQ=27.81;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=1.59;NEGATIVE_TRAIN_SITE;QD=25.5;ReadPosRankSum=0.572;SOR=0.922;VQSLOD=-2.735;culprit=DP  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  ./.:5,6:11:99:224,0,156 0/1:5,6:11:99:224,0,156
chr1    12719   .   G   C   255.34  VQSRTrancheSNP99.80to100.00 AC=1;AF=0.5;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=-0.922;ClippingRankSum=-0.198;DP=7;ExcessHet=0.0067;FS=0;InbreedingCoeff=0.4331;MQ=24.5;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=-1.495;QD=17.02;ReadPosRankSum=1.5;SOR=3.126;VQSLOD=-28.96;culprit=MQ GT:AB:AD:DP:GQ:PL   0/1:0.29:2,5:7:42:126,0,42  ./.:0.29:2,5:7:42:126,0,42
chr1    12807   .   C   T   632.14  VQSRTrancheSNP99.80to100.00 AC=1;AF=0.5;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=0.274;ClippingRankSum=0.091;DP=8;ExcessHet=0.6699;FS=0;InbreedingCoeff=0.1197;MQ=25.46;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=-1.92;QD=4.58;ReadPosRankSum=0.099;SOR=0.169;VQSLOD=-19.01;culprit=MQ  GT:AB:AD:DP:GQ:PL   ./.:0.63:5,3:8:62:62,0,131  0/1:0.63:5,3:8:62:62,0,131
chr1    13418   .   G   A   499.96  VQSRTrancheSNP99.80to100.00 AC=1;AF=0.5;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=0.107;ClippingRankSum=-0.198;DP=14;ExcessHet=8.1325;FS=130.966;InbreedingCoeff=-0.139;MQ=27.08;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=-1.828;QD=2.45;ReadPosRankSum=0.396;SOR=7.784;VQSLOD=-121.2;culprit=FS GT:AB:AD:DP:GQ:PL   0/0:0.79:11,3:14:42:42,0,324    0/1:0.79:11,3:14:42:42,0,324
chr1    13613   .   T   A   1283.97 VQSRTrancheSNP99.80to100.00 AC=1;AF=0.5;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=0.296;ClippingRankSum=-0.331;DP=18;ExcessHet=9.0886;FS=272.752;InbreedingCoeff=-0.1711;MQ=24.89;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=-1.683;QD=3.36;ReadPosRankSum=0.912;SOR=9.17;VQSLOD=-314.4;culprit=FS GT:AB:AD:DP:GQ:PL   5/6:0.83:15,3:18:29:29,0,373    1/1:0.83:15,3:18:29:29,0,373
chr1    13813   .   T   G   5171.34 VQSRTrancheSNP99.80to100.00 AC=1;AF=0.5;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=0.198;ClippingRankSum=0.072;DP=14;ExcessHet=52.1025;FS=21.569;InbreedingCoeff=-0.5228;MQ=25.92;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=-1.849;QD=9.76;ReadPosRankSum=0.198;SOR=6.138;VQSLOD=-54.86;culprit=SOR    GT:AB:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL   2/3:0.79:11,3:14:93:0|1:13813_T_G:93,0,573  2/4:0.79:11,3:14:93:0|1:13813_T_G:93,0,573
chr1    13838   .   C   T   5734.11 VQSRTrancheSNP99.80to100.00 AC=1;AF=0.5;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=-0.122;ClippingRankSum=0.067;DP=13;ExcessHet=54.052;FS=42.046;InbreedingCoeff=-0.5357;MQ=26.23;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=-1.92;QD=8.69;ReadPosRankSum=0.406;SOR=7.753;VQSLOD=-79.69;culprit=SOR GT:AB:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL   1/1:0.77:10,3:13:96:0|1:13813_T_G:96,0,537  2/1:0.77:10,3:13:96:0|1:13813_T_G:96,0,537
chr1    14397   .   CTGT    C   1894.87 VQSRTrancheINDEL99.00to100.00   AC=1;AF=0.5;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=-0.146;ClippingRankSum=0;DP=20;ExcessHet=7.9686;FS=1.729;InbreedingCoeff=-0.1149;MQ=32.16;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=-0.566;NEGATIVE_TRAIN_SITE;QD=5.98;ReadPosRankSum=1.71;SOR=0.833;VQSLOD=-2.874;culprit=QD   GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/2:17,3:20:75:75,0,843 0/9:17,3:20:75:75,0,843
```

Comment: You'd might find `regex` helpful for this.

Comment: @grumpyp I agree, I read a few other posts about using `replace()` on fractions and they used `regex` but I am honestly not sure where to begin with adding `regex`

Comment: [regular expression is\_fraction : Python : regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523110/regular-expression-is-fraction-python-regex) Here's a place to begin. Also check the regex documentation. [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) is your friend.

Comment: `re.match()` would be my thought check it out here https://www.guru99.com/python-regular-expressions-complete-tutorial.html#5

Comment: @PranavHosangadi It does not. I don't care if it is a fraction or not.

Comment: @grumpyp that is a possible solution but I would like to hopefully  made a generalize rule for the pattern

Comment: @neuron A regexp solution would probably work better with whole lines. Can you give some example lines from the original text file (i.e. before any processing)?

Comment: @ekhumoro I added an example of a smaller dataset. The concept is the same but the fraction in the file aren't nearly as complex. If I added one line from the full file would take up the entire screen.

Comment: One line of the full file also exceed the max number of characters I can put in a post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex for that:

```
import re
d = {'0/0': '0', './.': '-'}
re.sub('(?:\d+/\d+|\./\.)', lambda m: d.get(m.group(), '1'), text)
```

Assuming this input:

```
text = '''chr1    10397   .   CCCCTAA C   943.64  VQSRTrancheINDEL99.00to100.00   AC=1;AF=0.5;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=1.07;ClippingRankSum=-0.322;DP=11;ExcessHet=0.2139;FS=1.056;InbreedingCoeff=0.1828;MQ=27.81;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=1.59;NEGATIVE_TRAIN_SITE;QD=25.5;ReadPosRankSum=0.572;SOR=0.922;VQSLOD=-2.735;culprit=DP  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:5,6:11:99:224,0,156 0/1:5,6:11:99:224,0,156
chr1    12719   .   G   C   255.34  VQSRTrancheSNP99.80to100.00 AC=1;AF=0.5;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=-0.922;ClippingRankSum=-0.198;DP=7;ExcessHet=0.0067;FS=0;InbreedingCoeff=0.4331;MQ=24.5;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=-1.495;QD=17.02;ReadPosRankSum=1.5;SOR=3.126;VQSLOD=-28.96;culprit=MQ GT:AB:AD:DP:GQ:PL   0/1:0.29:2,5:7:42:126,0,42  0/1:0.29:2,5:7:42:126,0,42
'''
```

output:

```
chr1    10397   .   CCCCTAA C   943.64  VQSRTrancheINDEL99.00to100.00   AC=1;AF=0.5;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=1.07;ClippingRankSum=-0.322;DP=11;ExcessHet=0.2139;FS=1.056;InbreedingCoeff=0.1828;MQ=27.81;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=1.59;NEGATIVE_TRAIN_SITE;QD=25.5;ReadPosRankSum=0.572;SOR=0.922;VQSLOD=-2.735;culprit=DP  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1:5,6:11:99:224,0,156 1:5,6:11:99:224,0,156
chr1    12719   .   G   C   255.34  VQSRTrancheSNP99.80to100.00 AC=1;AF=0.5;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=-0.922;ClippingRankSum=-0.198;DP=7;ExcessHet=0.0067;FS=0;InbreedingCoeff=0.4331;MQ=24.5;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=-1.495;QD=17.02;ReadPosRankSum=1.5;SOR=3.126;VQSLOD=-28.96;culprit=MQ GT:AB:AD:DP:GQ:PL   1:0.29:2,5:7:42:126,0,42  1:0.29:2,5:7:42:126,0,42
```

###### shorter example

```
text = './. ?/? x/x 198/321 0/0 1/1'
re.sub('(?:\d+/\d+|\./\.)', lambda m: d.get(m.group(), '1'), text)
```

output: `'- ?/? x/x 1 0 1'`

##### with a file

```
import re
d = {'0/0': '0', './.': '-'}

with open("output.txt", "w") as out:
    for line in open(input, "r+"):
        out.write(re.sub('(?:\d+/\d+|\./\.)', lambda m: d.get(m.group(), '1'), line))
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer might better, but I hate RegEx ! ;)

```py
def replace(fraction):
    fraction = list(map(str.strip, fraction.split("/")))
    if fraction == ["0", "0"]:
        return "0"
    elif fraction == [".", "."]:
        return "-"
    else:
        return "1"

print(replace("0/0"))
print(replace("./."))
print(replace("1/1"))
print(replace(" 1 /1"))
print(replace(" 0           /                           1")) # this even works with whitespaces and tabs around 1
```

Output:

```py
0
-
1
1
1
```